# USB not working in OpenBSD 5.6 installer

Tags: usb, keyboard, openbsd

I'm trying to install OpenBSD 5.6 amd64 on my 2012 Mac mini (quad-core Intel i7), but USB stops working partway through the boot sequence, as evidenced by my lighted keyboard going dark. Without a working keyboard, I am unable to proceed through the installer.

The keyboard works just fine during installation and use under OpenBSD 5.5 amd64 on this Mac mini. Attempting to boot the 5.6 installer on another Mac mini (dual-core i5) also results in the same issue, so it's not something wonky with this particular machine.

I have tried install56.iso, install56.fs, cd56.iso, and bsd.rd from the release version of 5.6. I have also tried install56.iso from two recent snapshots. None of these work.

Here's the text output on the screen as it boots, videoed and hand-transcribed (there might be typos):

```
CD-ROM: 90
Loading /5.6/AMD64/CDBOOT
probing: pc0 mem[568K 63K 511M 510M 1197M 80K 2M 14070M a20=on]
disk: hd0+ hd1+ sd0* cd0
>> OpenBSD/amd64 CDBOOT 3.23
boot>
cannot open cd0a:/etc/random.seed: No such file or directory
booting cd0a:/5.6/amd64/bsd.rd: 3189664+1368975+2401280+0+517104 [72+350160+227754]=0x7b0838
entry point at 0x1000160 [7205c766, 34000004, 24448b12, 6670a304]
kbc: cmd word write error
Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
        The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
Copyright (c) 1995-2014 OpenBSD. All rights reserved.  http://www.OpenBSD.org

OpenBSD 5.6-current (RAMDISK_CD) #551: Fri Nov 21 10:20:00 MST 2014
    deraadt@amd64.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/RAMDISK_CD
RTC BIOS diagnostic error 7f<ROM_cksum,config_unit,memory_size,fixed_disk,invalid_time>
real mem = 17065648128 (16275MB)
avail mem = 16610545664 (15841MB)
mainbus0 at root
bios0 at mainbus0: SMBIOS rev. 2.4 @ 0xe0000 (83 entries)
bios0: vendor Apple Inc. version "MM61.88Z.0106.B04.1309191433" date 09/19/2013
bios0: Apple Inc. Macmini6,2
acpi0 at bios0: rev 2
acpi0: sleep states S0 S3 S4 S5
acpi0: tables DSDT FACP HPET APIC SBST ECDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT DMAR MCFG
acpimadt0 at acpi0 addr 0xfee00000: PC-AT compat
cpu0 at mainbus0: apid 0 (boot processor)
cpu0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz, 2295.13 MHz
cpu0: FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,MCOV,PAT,PSE36,CFLUSH,DS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM,PBE,SSE3,PCLMUL,DTES64,MWAIT,DS-CPL,VMX,EST,TM2,SSSE3,CX16,xTPR,PDCM,PCID,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,x2APIC,POPCNT,DEADLINE,AES,XSAVE,AVX,F16C,RDRAND,NXE,LONG,LAHF,PERF,ITSC,FSGSBASE,SMEP,ERMS
cpu0: 256KB 64b/line 8-way L2 cache
```

(There's a discontinuity here, there might be some lines missing)

```
ppb2 at pci2 dev 0 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0x1547 rev 0x03: msi
pci3 at ppb2 bus 6
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0x1547 (class system subclass miscellaneous, rev 0x03) at pci3 dev 0 function 0 not configured
ppb3 at pci2 dev 3 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0x1547 rev 0x03: msi
pci4 at ppb3 bus 7
ppb4 at pci2 dev 4 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0x1547 rev 0x03: msi
pci5 at ppb4 bus 56
ppb5 at pci2 dev 5 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0x1547 rev 0x03: msi
pci6 at ppb5 bus 105
ppb6 at pci2 dev 6 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0x1547 rev 0x03: msi
pci7 at ppb6 bus 106
vga1 at pci0 dev 2 function 0 "Intel HD Graphics 4000" rev 0x09
wsdisplay0 at vga1 mux 1: console(80x25, vt100 emulation)
"Intel 7 Series xHCI" rev 0x04 at pci0 dev 20 function 0 not configured
"Intel 7 Series MEI" rev 0x04 at pci0 dev 22 function 0 not configured
ehci0 at pci0 dev 26 function 0 "Intel 7 Series USB" rev 0x04: apic 2 int 23
usb0 at ehci0: USB revision 2.0
uhub0 at usb0 "Intel EHIC root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
"Intel 7 Series HD Audio" rev 0x04 at pci0 dev 27 function 0 not configured
ppb7 at pci0 dev 28 function 0 "Intel 7 Series PCIE" rev 0xc4: msi
pci8 at ppb7 bus 1
bge0 at pci8 dev 0 function 0 "Broadcom BCM57766" rev 0x01, unknown BCM57766 (0x57766001): msi, address [removed]
bgrphy0 at bge0 phy1: BCM57765 10/100/1000baseT PHY, rev. 1
sdhc0 at pci8 dev 0 function 1 "Broadcom SD Host Controller" rev 0x01: apic 2 int 17
sdhc0 at 0x10: can't map registers
ppb8 at pci0 dev 28 function 1 "Intel 7 Series PCIE" rev 0xc4: msi
pci9 at ppb8 bus 2
vendor "Broadcom", unknown product 0x4331 (class network subsclass miscellaneous, rev 0x02) at pci9 dev 0 function 0 not configured
ppb9 at pci0 dev 28 function 2 "Intel 7 Series PCIE" rev 0xc4: msi
pci10 at ppb9 bus 3
"AT&T/Lucent FW643 1394" rev 0x08 at pci10 dev 0 function 0 not configured
ehci1 at pci0 dev 29 function 0 "Intel 7 Series USB" rev 0x04: apic 2 int 22
usb1 at ehic1: USB revision 2.0
uhub1 at usb1 "Intel EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
"Intel HM77 LPC" rev 0x04 at pci0 dev 31 function 0 not configured
ahci0 at pci0 dev 31 function 2 "Intel 7 Series AHCI" rev 0x04: msi, AHCI 1.3
scsibus0 at ahci0: 32 targets
sd0 at scsibus0 targ 0 lun 0: <ATA, Samsung SSD 850, EXM0> SCSI3 0/direct fixed
naa.50025388a069068d
sd0: 244198MB, 512 bytes/sector, 500118192 sectors, thin
sd1 at scsibus0 targ 1 lun 0: <ATA, Samsung SSD 850, EXM0> SCSI3 0/direct fixed
naa.50025388a0690757
sd1: 244198MB, 512 bytes/sector, 500118192 sectors, thin
"Intel 7 Series SMBus" rev 0x04 at pci0 dev 31 function 3 not configured
isa0 at mainbus0
com0 at isa0 port 0x3f8/8 irq 4: ns8250, no fifo
uhub2 at uhub0 port 1 "vendor 0x8087 product 0x0024" rev 2.00/0.00 addr 2
uhub3 at uhub1 port 1 "vendor 0x8087 product 0x0024" rev 2.00/0.00 addr 2
uhub4 at uhub3 port 8 "vendor 0x0424 product 0x2512" rev 2.00/b.b3 addr 3
uhub5 at uhub4 port 1 "Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 4
uhidev0 at uhub5 port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "vendor 0x05ac product 0x820a" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 5
uhidev0: iclass 3/1, 1 report id
ukbd0 at uhidev0 reportid 1
wskbd0 at ukbd0: console keyboard, using wsdisplay0
uhidev1 at uhub5 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "vendor 0x05ac product 0x820b" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 6
uhidev1: iclass 3/1, 2 report ids
uhid at uhidev1 reportid 2 not configured
"Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller" rev 2.00/0.79 addr 7 at uhub5 port 3 not configured
uhidev2 at uhub4 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "Apple, Inc. IR Receiver" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 8
uhidev2: iclass 3/0, 38 report ids
uhid at uhidev2 reportid 36 not configured
uhid at uhidev2 reportid 37 not configured
uhid at uhidev2 reportid 38 not configured
softraid0 at root
scsibus1 at softraid0: 256 targets
softraid0: trying to bring up sd2 degraded
sd2 at scsibus1 targ 1 lun 0: <OPENBSD, SR RAID 1, 005> SCSI2 0/direct fixed
sd2: 244190MB, 512 bytes/sector, 500102858 sectors
softraid0: roaming device  -> sd1a
root on rd0a swap on rd0b dump on rd0b
erase ^?, werase ^W, kill ^U, intr ^C, status ^T

Welcome to the OpenBSD/amd64 5.6 installation program.
(I)nstall, (U)pgrade, (A)utoinstall or (S)hell? _
```

There is some mention of USB and the keyboard as it's booting, but at this point my backlit keyboard is unlit and pressing keys doesn't do anything. No other keyboard I have works. I have tried plugging in the keyboard to all the USB ports on the system, it does not help.

Any ideas what the problem could be? Is there any way to control this system without needing a USB keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the issue was, but it appears to have been fixed in the current branch. You can download a snapshot (e.g. from http://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/amd64/ or another mirror) and it should work now.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @jimmij It was intended to be a complete answer. I've edited it to be a little clearer, but basically the answer is: this bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem installing OpenBSD 5.7 on a Jetway barebones box (JBC375F3AW-2930-B, but this probably applies to most or all models).  The fix was to go into the BIOS setup program, and on the "Advanced" screen, set the "OS Selection" item to "Android".